# Does Azure EventHubConsumerClient time-out after 40 minutes?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I am reading events from an Azure EventHub cluster synchronously via the receiveFromPartition method on the EventHubConsumerClient class.

I create the client once like so:

```
EventHubConsumerClient eventHubConsumerClient = new EventHubClientBuilder()
            .connectionString(eventHubConnectionString)
            .consumerGroup(consumerGroup)
            .buildConsumerClient());
```

I then just use a ScheduledExecutorService to retrieve events every 1.5s via:

```
IterableStream<PartitionEvent> receivedEvents = eventHubConsumerClient.receiveFromPartition(
                partitionId, 1, eventPosition);
```

I have been running similar logic using V3 of the SDK in production without issue, but after upgrading to V5 I'm having issues.

When I kick off this loop all seems to work fine, but after 40 minutes or so of successful execution the EventHubConsumerClient starts timing out on request (after 2 mins of waiting), even though new data is definitely available in the EventHub instance.

A small example of the corresponding logs:

```
com.azure.core.amqp.implementation.RetryUtil: TimeoutException error occurred. Retrying operation.
com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.implementation.SynchronousEventSubscriber$ReceiveTimeoutTask: Work: 5. Timeout encountered, disposing of subscriber.
```

Is this a bug or is there a known limit in how long a connection such as this can persist in the new SDK version? If so, how can I ensure a long-lived connection that I can rely on?

Any advise would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This looks like a timeout error when performing the receive operation due to a transient network error and all retry attempts failed. Can you share a fully reproducible sample here or file a bug report [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug_report.md&title=%5BBUG%5D)?

Comment: Also, if you want to have a long-running receiver, then it's recommended to use `EventProcessorClient` which will run continuously and handle all recoverable errors. It allows you to receive events from all partitions. It also allows you to checkpoint and load balance partitions among multiple instances of the processor client. Read more about the [processor](http://aka.ms/eh-processor) and here's a [code sample](https://aka.ms/eh-processor-java) for using the processor.

Comment: It's an intermittent issue and can be solved by closing and re-creating the client when a timeout is detected (i.e. doesn't seem like a firewall or logic issue) - also the V3 equivalent works as expected long-lived within the same network

Comment: How do you verify new data is available? Can you try running 2 consumer groups in parallel and see if one receiver stops while the other one still receives?